# how to solve .intl error

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions

I installed LAMP (php 7.2) on my VPS server.

When I try to install magento (debian 9) I get error extension .intl

I run command line below:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https lsb-release ca-certificates
sudo wget -O /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/php.gpg https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg
echo "deb https://packages.sury.org/php/ $(lsb_release -sc) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/php.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install php7.2-intl
```

[image]

[image]

Unfortunately, I still have this error. Does anyone know how to solve this? It gives Vote

Comment: You should enable the php.intl php extension in your php.ini files and restart server and check again

Answer (score 0):

Your current PHP version in use is `7.0.26` (see *PHP Version Check* in your screenshot). So either make sure your webspace is configured to actually use `PHP 7.2` or install `intl` for `PHP 7.0`.

Switching PHP versions in not particularly a Magento question and fits best to stackoverflow.com - where you can find answers on that topic already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561203/how-to-change-php-version-in-htaccess-in-server. But to answer your first comment, you can add

```
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php72 .php
```

to your .htaccess file.

Comment: I run command php --version and get: 
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.1-1+0~20180105151615.16+stretch~1.gbpd3910a, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
Can you help to install version php 7.2 so that magento will show that I have version 7.2?

Comment: PHP version on CLI can differ from what is used in the given webspace. Are you using any management panel for your webspace or are you configuring your system on CLI only?

Comment: @Sylvester, updated my answer with a reference to stackoverflow.com.